# Intellij maven "cannot resolve symbol" even though package was successful

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, word-cloud

**My problem:**
I have created a Maven project. I have imported a repository (called Kumo). Within the Maven config XML file, I have had no errors come up. The error I get occurs when I try to use one of the classes.
It tells me: `Cannot resolve symbol 'WordCloud'`

**What I have tried with (I think) no results:**

- Invalidating the caches
- Restarting IntelliJ
- Reimporting all Maven projects button
- Generate Sources button
- Download Sources button
- Adding a compile XML tag
- Trying to create this project on Windows yields the same result

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>kumo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kennycason</groupId>
            <artifactId>kumo</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Test_1.java:

```
public class Test_1 {
    WordCloud cloud;
    FrequencyAnalyzer analyzer;
}
```

Test_2.java:

```
package Example;

public class Test2 {
    WordCloud cloud;
    FrequencyAnalyzer analyzer;
}
```

[image: layout]

[image: pom.xml]

[image: what classes look like]

Comment: try using `import` assuming that the class exists in the `kumo` jar

Comment: I tried doing that and it couldn't find anything to import. What worked was adding the 4 sub-dependencies to the pom.xml

Comment: Maybe you just want the `kumo-api`

Comment: go to the red word and press ctrl + enter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [kumo github repository](https://github.com/kennycason/kumo), you should use below dependency instead of `<artifactId>kumo</artifactId>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kennycason</groupId>
    <artifactId>kumo-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Let explain to you why `<artifactId>kumo</artifactId>` doesn't work. This pom is using `<project><dependencyManagement>` to announcing the dependency informations. Maven will import dependencies from `<project><dependencies>` section instead of `<project><dependencyManagement>`.

You may check the pom of `kumo` in your local Maven repository in `${user}\.m2\repository\com\kennycason\`(windows).

And Maven's dependencyManagement is mainly used for below items,

1. When you have a set of projects that inherits a common parent it's possible to put all information about the dependency in the common POM and have simpler references to the artifacts in the child POMs.
2. to control the versions of artifacts used in transitive dependencies. It means if you define the version of an artifact in `<dependencyManagement>` section, then you could just declare it without the version in `<dependencies>` section.

You may also refer to [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) for more example to further studies.

Comment: While I solved my issue another way, this is definitely the right way to do it and includes a good explanation of WHY as well. Thank you, I now understand Maven better too.

Answer (score 1):

Craziest thing. Apparently the [Maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.kennycason/kumo/1.11) for version 1.11 has no JAR associated with it, so it cannot be added directly. Instead, each of the 4 sub-modules have to have their dependencies added directly and all of a sudden it works. I am not sure *why* this is the case, as the total package includes them as dependencies. Still, I have solved my own problem after talking to my animals about it.

Comment: Not the first or last time something like that ends up in maven repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Should you update maven to download the dependencies and import WordCloud class to your java file? This error may be caused by the IDE cannot find the class.